# if x is a real number, and x > 0, is the following possible $\frac 1 {\{x\}} + \{x\} = 1$?

Tags: calculus

if x is a real number, and x > 0.

for example x = 10.7, then floor of x = 10, and the remainder of floor of x = 0.7.

is the following possible?

$\frac 1 {\{x\}} + \{x\} = 1$    ?

where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$

Thanks!

Comment: note that it is equivalent that exists $0<t<1$ such that $\frac{1}{t}+t=1$

Comment: Both terms are positive and one of them is greater than $1$.  No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $y = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, i.e. the remainder of floor(x). Assume $y$ satisfies the equation

$$ \frac{1}{y} + y = 1.$$

Multiply both sides by $y$. You get a quadratic equation. Does it have solutions? What does this mean for your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Is not possible. Let's see, if $t=x-[x]$ is the remainder of the floor function, then if $$t+\frac{1}{t}=1 \iff t^2+1=t \iff t^2-t+1=0.$$ The discriminant of the quadratic polynomial $p(t)=t^2-t+1$ is $$\Delta=(-1)^4-4(1)(1)=-3<0,$$ so the equation $t^2-t+1=0$ has no real roots.